# Firebird .NET interoperation

Tags: .net, sqlite, interop, firebird

Has anyone had experience with using Firebird in interoperating with the .NET framework and if so, how did it go?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've used firebird in a commercial desktop application.

Its performance is fine, until you deal with queries that return large result sets. In those cases we found that the .net provider for firebird was performing in an inefficient way. You may find that this isn't a problem for you -- if queries are specific enough they don't return large result sets.

For us, the performance remained passable.

It was certainly feature complete, in the sense that it could do everything we wanted it do. The tooling is also sufficient to help with troubleshooting, table design etc.

As a sql-server dev i found firebird's sql syntax close enough that we handled problems through general googling and without needing to ask for help from stackoverflow.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [Sinática Monitor](http://www.sinatica.com). It's a firebird monitoring tool and it's written in C# with .net 2.
Also check out the [Firebird .Net Data Provider](http://www.firebirdsql.org/index.php?op=files&id=netprovider).